# Copy qDebug() output

Tags: c++, qt, logging

I want to keep the qDebug() output on a log file and display it on the console, I've tried with this :

```
qDebug() << "Hand's up!";
QTextStream stream(stdout);
QTextStream out(&logFile);
out << stream.readAll();
```

but it doesn't work at all even if I remplace `stdout` with `stderr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a message handler you've created, there's a great minimal example here: [Nokia Wiki: how to redirect qDebug output to a file](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_redirect_qDebug_output_to_a_file). That'll allow you to use the qDebug() calls as normal and have it output, and you can tweak the message as it's being written out.

Comment: I would modify the code a bit since, for Fatal Messages, the program will abort before writing a message to the text file.

Comment: Good point, I wrote a variation of it a while back and forgot about fixing that.

Comment: I've tried yours and here is what I get `use of undeclared identifier 'qInstallMsgHandler'; did you mean 'qInstallMessageHandler' `, so I corrected and it's even worst

Comment: You're right Samoth, the API has changed with Qt5. The new function handler has an extra parameter. See the documentation for [qInstallMessageHandler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler)

Comment: Well now it's done, you lead me on a good way but this isn't up to date, you should take a look here https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler to see the new install method of a message handler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And is there a way to get project name inside of the log without hard code it?

Comment: You can set the application name when you create your instance of `QApplication` and then access it from that class anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QDebug` class instead of just using `qDebug()`.

`qDebug()` creates a debug object with default settings, like where to send the output string. If you create an object by yourself, you have more control over it.

Comment: This will only work for your own debug messages. For code you haven't written, like in the Qt Libraries, you'll need to use Nocholas Smith's answer to capture those messages.

Comment: @RobbieE in fact, I just want mine. But I don't understand how to copy the stream to a file without deleting it from the output